# Installing restricted drivers application

Tags: drivers, broadcom, restricted

I'm having trouble with my internet dard (which is a Broadcom).

I have been told to install the restricted drivers application and then look for a proprietary driver.

So:--

can anyone tell me where I can find the restricted drivers application please?

Apparently I'm to put it on the desktop and install it from there.

I was told another way: as apt-get can't find the application, supply it with a path. Others say no -- this is a one-off: simply get the application and install it manually.

So, where from?

Bill Bennett.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install anything. It's included by default. You should find in the dash if you search for "drivers" or something similar. You don't say which version of Ubuntu you're using, but in 14.04LTS, it's in the right-most tab in `software-properties-gtk`. If you're using an older version of Ubuntu, the application is called Jockey.